# Warning "i686-mingw32-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail" while cross compiling ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compiling

I get the following warning while trying to cross compile ffmpeg as below

```
$ ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libgsm --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --arch=x86 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-avisynth --enable-w32threads --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='i686-mingw32-gcc' --enable-memalign-hack --disable-doc --enable-avfilter --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-ffprobe
```

Configure ran fine but with the following warning

```
License: GPL version 3 or later
Creating config.mak and config.h...
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged

WARNING: i686-mingw32-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
```

How do I provide `i686-mingw32-pkg-config` to configure?

Comment: What is the source OS your're using...

Comment: Ubuntu, but why would that matter?

Comment: Because you could have been using Windows Or ecomstation.

Comment: @S B Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The missing library is located in the package [`mingw-w64-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/mingw-w64-tools/filelist).

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MinGw64. There it's this missing package:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```